# Make First Two Elements of a List<int> 0

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List with several values in it, like:

```
var myList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

I would like to have a new List that's ***List { 0, 0, 3}***

How can this be done with using LINQ, rather than:

```
myList[0] = myList[1] = 0;
```

Comment: Isn't [Linq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) a _query_ language, not a manipulation language?

Comment: All the (correct) answers so far look way complicated. Is it possible that you try to solve an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: I am actually trying to solve a problem where I have to make the first elements of a List = 0. After that I go through it and for each 1 I change another List<bool> to true. I'm sorry if I don't make much sense, I just wanted to know if there's a more optimized way of doing so, rather than making the first two values = 0 with indexers.

Comment: What you already have is way better than attempting to use Linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try looking at the index when selecting the values, ignoring the first two values.

```
var myList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

myList = myList.Select((x, index) => index < 2 ? 0 : x).ToList(); // { 0, 0, 3 }
```

Do note that this is creating a new list rather than manipulating the original list. Linq is a query language.

Comment: Thank you, this helped out a lot!

Comment: If you dont mind, How could you do this without lambda function? It would help me :)

Comment: @JoseAviles In that case just do what the OP did in their post.

Answer (score -1):

```
      var myList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};

       myList = new[] { 0, 0 }.Concat(myList.Skip(2)).ToList();

        foreach (var x in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
```

outputs 0 0 3

this is basic solution, check array sizes for nulls etc.

Comment: You don't need the `ToList` after `Skip`.